# Solution of functional equation with sums and products

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

I'm not very familiar with functional equations,so I really need help.
Is there some method to obtain functions $b_i, i=1,2$ from
$$\displaystyle{\Big(a_1(u)b_1(v)+a_2(u)b_2(v)-\sqrt{a_1^2(u)+a_2^2(u)}\sqrt{b_1^2(v)+b_2^2(v)}\Big)^2=f(u,v),}$$ where functions $a_i$ and $f(u,v)$ are known functions. I tried by switching to trigonometric functions by dividing with $\sqrt{a_1^2(u)+a_2^2(u)}$ but it got me nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

We will assume that all variables and functions are real valued. Define the functions
$$ a_3(u)\! := \!\sqrt{a_1^2(u) \!+\! a_2^2(u)}, \;\; 
   b_3(v)\!:=\!\sqrt{b_1^2(v) \!+\! b_2^2(v)}, \;\;
   r(u,\!v)\! := \!\sqrt{f(u,\!v)}. \tag{1} $$
For the functional equation define the new function
$$ e(u,v) := r(u,v) - (a_1(u)b_1(v) + a_2(u)b_2(v) - a_3(u)b_3(v)). \tag{2} $$
The functional equation now is simply that $\ e(u,v) = 0\ $ for all
$\ u,v.\ $

Let $\ u_1,u_2,u_3\ $ be three distinct numbers. We solve the three
 linear equations
$$ e(u_1,v) = 0, \quad e(u_2,v) = 0, \quad e(u_3,v) = 0. \tag{3} $$ 
for $\ b_1(v),\ b_2(v),\ b_3(v)\ $ and check that
$\ b_3^2(v) = b_1^2(v) + b_2^2(v).\ $